# How I center my HTML iframe in Android webivew?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-webview

I have an iframe in my Android webview that I am loading like this:

```
     String folderPath = "file:android_asset/";
     String fileName = "index.html";
     String file = folderPath + fileName;
     webView.loadUrl(file);
```

The iframe is loaded via HTML and CSS files located in my `android/assests` folder. The HTML and CSS look like this. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"  />
    <div class="abs-frame-container">
    <iframe 
      id="my_frame"
      src="my web page link"
      scrolling="no"
      allowtransparency="true" 
      style="border:none;overflow:hidden">
    </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS

```
#my_frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 117%;
  height: 100%;
}

#abs-frame-container{
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 0%;
    position: relative;
}
```

The webpage in iframe shows fine in the webview. I want to center (vertical alignment) my iframe in the webview so that it aligns automatically based on the webview dimensions (height). Would appreciate a lot if someone could help me how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can call custom JavaScript on `WebView` directly from Java/Kotlin. It is explained in [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#UsingJavaScript).

You can then make [JavaScript script that adds CSS styles](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) to parts of loaded `html` page, and center your `iframe` that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So the CSS file that I already have is not sufficient to do the trick?

Comment: There is no direct way to apply css file from android code. But if you already have desired css, it shouldn't be hard to "translate" that to javascript. I attached a link in my answer with some examples.